# Translate javascript function in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code in jS :

```
function stripHTMLWithLinks(c) {
    var BodyContents = /([\s\S]*\<body[^\>]*\>)([\s\S]*)(\<\/body\>[\s\S]*)/i ;
    var h = c.match(BodyContents);

  if (h != null && h[2]) {
        c = h[2]; 
  }

    c = c.replace(/<a\s.*?href\s*=\s*"(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, "$2 [$1]");
    c = c.replace(/<a\s.*?href\s*=\s*'(.*?)'.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, "$2 [$1]");
    c = c.replace(/\/\/--\>/gi, "");
    c = c.replace(/(\n)/gi,"");
    c = c.replace(/(\r)/gi,"");
    c = c.replace(/<title[^\>]*\>[\s\S]*\<\/title\>/gi,"");
    c = c.replace(/<br\s*\/\s*>/gi,"\n");
    c = c.replace(/(<\/h.>|<\/p>|<\/div>)/gi, "$1\n\n");
    c = c.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"");
    c = c.replace(/&lt;/g,"<");
    c = c.replace(/&gt;/g,">");
    c = c.replace(/&nbsp;/g," ");
    return c;
}
```

I need a function that will extract the body content. All the examples that I saw here were kinda fixed on a particular example , and i need it on dynamic basis. This function can do it for me, I just need it in php.

Answer (score 0):

This should be really easy to transcode to PHP.
Look for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php) and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace.php) in the PHP Manual.

Comment: True, but OP asked for translation to PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Try [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
$html = "<body><a href='http://example.com'>Something</a> <b>big</b> is coming</body>";
echo strip_tags($html); // Something big is coming
```